# Input format for MaxEnt OpenNLP implementation?

Tags: opennlp

I'm trying to use the OpenNLP implementation of the Maximum Entropy classifier but it seems documentation is quite lacking and despite this library is apparently designed for easy of use I cannot find a single example and/or specification for the input file format (i.e., the training set).

Anybody knows where to find this or a minimal working example of training?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenNLP's format is quite flexible. If you want to use the MaxEnt classifier in OpenNLP there are a few steps involved.

Here is sample code with comments:

```
package example;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import opennlp.tools.ml.maxent.GISTrainer;
import opennlp.tools.ml.model.Event;
import opennlp.tools.ml.model.MaxentModel;
import opennlp.tools.tokenize.WhitespaceTokenizer;
import opennlp.tools.util.FilterObjectStream;
import opennlp.tools.util.MarkableFileInputStreamFactory;
import opennlp.tools.util.ObjectStream;
import opennlp.tools.util.PlainTextByLineStream;
import opennlp.tools.util.TrainingParameters;

public class ReadData {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        // this is the data file ...
        // the format is <LIST of FEATURES separated by spaces> <outcome>
        // change the file to fit your needs
        File f=new File("football.dat");

        // we need to create an ObjectStream of events for the trainer..
        //   First create an InputStreamFactory -- given a file we can create an InputStream, required for resetting...
        MarkableFileInputStreamFactory factory=new MarkableFileInputStreamFactory(f);
        // create a PlainTextByLineInputStream -- Note: you can create your own Stream that can handle binary files or data that
        //                                     --       crosses two line...
        ObjectStream<String> stream=new PlainTextByLineStream(factory, Charset.defaultCharset());
        //  Now you have a stream of string you need to convert it to a stream of events...
        //  I use a custom FilterObjectStream which simply takes a line, breaks it up into tokens,
        //  uses all except the last as the features [context] and the last token as the outcome class
        ObjectStream<Event> eventStream=new FilterObjectStream<String, Event>(stream) {
            @Override
            public Event read() throws IOException {
                String line=samples.read();
                if (line==null) return null;

                String[] parts=WhitespaceTokenizer.INSTANCE.tokenize(line);
                String[] context=Arrays.copyOf(parts, parts.length-1);

                System.out.println(parts[parts.length-1]+" "+Arrays.toString(context));
                return new Event(parts[parts.length-1], context);
            }
        };


        TrainingParameters parameters=new TrainingParameters();
        // By default OpenNLP uses a cutoff of 5 (a feature has to occur 5 times before it is used)
        // use 1 for my small dataset
        parameters.put(GISTrainer.CUTOFF_PARAM, 1);

        GISTrainer trainer=new GISTrainer();
        // the report map is supposed to mark when default values are assigned...
        Map<String,String> reportMap=new HashMap<>();
        // DONT FORGET TO INITIALIZE THE TRAINER!!!
        trainer.init(parameters, reportMap);
        MaxentModel model=trainer.train(eventStream);

        // Now we have a model -- you should test on a test set, but 
        // this is a toy example... so I am just resetting the eventstream.
        eventStream.reset();
        Event evt=null;
        while ( (evt=eventStream.read())!=null ){
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(evt.getContext())+":  ");
            // Evaluate the context from the event using our model.
            // you would want to calculate summary statistics..
            double[] p=model.eval(evt.getContext());
            System.out.print(model.getBestOutcome(p)+"  ");
            if (model.getBestOutcome(p).equals(evt.getOutcome())){
                System.out.println("CORRECT");
            }else{
                System.out.println("INCORRECT");                
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Football.dat:

```
home=man_united Beckham=false Scholes=true Neville=true Henry=true Kanu=true Parlour=false Ferguson=confident Wengler=tense arsenal_lost_previous man_united_won_previous arsenal
home=man_united Beckham=true Scholes=false Neville=true Henry=false Kanu=true Parlour=false Ferguson=tense Wengler=confident arsenal_won_previous man_united_lost_previous man_united
home=man_united Beckham=false Scholes=true Neville=true Henry=true Kanu=true Parlour=false Ferguson=tense Wengler=tense arsenal_lost_previous man_united_won_previous tie
home=man_united Beckham=true Scholes=true Neville=false Henry=true Kanu=false Parlour=false Ferguson=confident Wengler=confident arsenal_won_previous man_united_won_previous tie
home=man_united Beckham=false Scholes=true Neville=true Henry=true Kanu=true Parlour=false Ferguson=confident Wengler=tense arsenal_won_previous man_united_won_previous arsenal
home=man_united Beckham=false Scholes=true Neville=true Henry=false Kanu=true Parlour=false Ferguson=confident Wengler=confident arsenal_won_previous man_united_won_previous man_united
home=man_united Beckham=true Scholes=true Neville=false Henry=true Kanu=true Parlour=false Ferguson=confident Wengler=tense arsenal_won_previous man_united_won_previous man_united
home=arsenal Beckham=false Scholes=true Neville=true Henry=true Kanu=true Parlour=false Ferguson=confident Wengler=tense arsenal_lost_previous man_united_won_previous arsenal
home=arsenal Beckham=true Scholes=false Neville=true Henry=false Kanu=true Parlour=false Ferguson=tense Wengler=confident arsenal_won_previous man_united_lost_previous arsenal
home=arsenal Beckham=false Scholes=true Neville=true Henry=true Kanu=true Parlour=false Ferguson=tense Wengler=tense arsenal_lost_previous man_united_won_previous tie
home=arsenal Beckham=true Scholes=true Neville=false Henry=true Kanu=false Parlour=false Ferguson=confident Wengler=confident arsenal_won_previous man_united_won_previous man_united
home=arsenal Beckham=false Scholes=true Neville=true Henry=true Kanu=true Parlour=false Ferguson=confident Wengler=tense arsenal_won_previous man_united_won_previous arsenal
home=arsenal Beckham=false Scholes=true Neville=true Henry=false Kanu=true Parlour=false Ferguson=confident Wengler=confident arsenal_won_previous man_united_won_previous man_united
home=arsenal Beckham=true Scholes=true Neville=false Henry=true Kanu=true Parlour=false Ferguson=confident Wengler=tense arsenal_won_previous man_united_won_previous arsenal
```

Hope it Helps

Comment: Had already solved the issue but thanks for the comprehensive answer!

Comment: Do you also know how to pass both textual features and numeric ones? That is, how I tell the system to interpret some values as numerical if I want to pass e.g. a vector of real values as features?

Comment: (sorry it has been awhile...) I am not sure OpenNLP handle numeric features.  Have you considered using logistic regression with categorical and numeric values?